# Socket is not throwing "would block" SocketException

Tags: c#, sockets, socketexception

I'm trying to force a socket to throw a `SocketException` with the error code for "would block" when sending data by overfilling available buffers, but I cannot get it to happen.  Here is a small console application that I would think would exhibit the behavior:

```
namespace BlockingSocketTest
{
    using System;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Sockets;
    using System.Threading;

    internal class Program
    {
        const int Port = 65111;
        const int BufferSize = 4;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Create the server
            Socket server = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port));
            server.Listen(1);
            server.BeginAccept(HandleAcceptConnection, server);

            // Create the client
            Socket client = new Socket(SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            client.SendBufferSize = BufferSize;
            client.Blocking = false;
            client.Connect(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port));

            // Sleep to ensure HandleAcceptConnection completes
            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            // Send too much data
            Console.WriteLine("Sending data to the server");
            int bytesSent = client.Send(new byte[BufferSize * 3]);
            Console.WriteLine($"Sent {bytesSent} bytes");
        }

        static void HandleAcceptConnection(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            Socket server = (Socket)asyncResult.AsyncState;
            Socket clientConnection = server.EndAccept(asyncResult);
            Console.WriteLine("Got a connection from " + clientConnection.RemoteEndPoint);

            // Make the buffer small, and don't read any data
            clientConnection.ReceiveBufferSize = BufferSize;
        }
    }
}
```

I set the send and receive buffer sizes to 4, and then send 12 bytes and never read any data on the receive side.  My understanding was:

- 4 bytes would be sent to the listening socket and sit there until I read them
- 4 bytes would sit in the sending socket until the receive side had room for them
- The remaining 4 bytes would cause a `SocketException`

However, when running this it's clear that all 12 bytes are sent:

```
Got a connection from [::ffff:127.0.0.1]:65009
Sending data to the server
Sent 12 bytes
```

What am I misunderstanding here?  What is holding those extra 4 bytes?

Comment: Can I ask what happens if you send 4 bytes three times, instead of 12 bytes all at once?

Comment: Similar behavior, all 4 bytes make it.